# What is composite baseline in UCM and when it will be used?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

What is Composite baseline in UCM?

When it will be used? Will it be used mainly when we have multiple components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference on "composite Baselines" is: "[Best practices for using composite baselines in UCM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5134.html)".

> Introduced in ClearCase v2002, composite baselines are a mechanism for grouping baselines into a collection. One baseline is designated as the composite, and other baselines become members of the composite

[image: composite baselines]

You do not necessarily have to use composite baselines when you have multiple components, but:

If you want to **remember the set of baselines existing at a given point on your Stream**, then having a rootless component able to record of the baseline of its member is useful.

In theory, you can have "composites of composites":

[image: multiple levels]

I wouldn't recommended it, though, because of the "**parasite baselines** (explained [briefly here](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/forum/31-clearcase/61275-cannot-upgrade-a-non-modifiable-ucm-component-to-new-baseline) and [here](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/forum/31-clearcase/45969-implementing-composite-baseline-on-existing-pvob-and-ucm-projects))

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the "composites of composites" as well. However, some of our customers found that if they automatically document the changes of baselines (including composite and recommended baselines) with R&D Reporter for ClearCase, they are able to handle with that.

Comment: @Tamir: you mean you are taking into account dependency overrides, which triggers baselines on components which doesn't include any new version in it? We experience such an increase in the number of those "parasite baseline" created on components which hadn't changed) that we quickly dropped the multi-level composite model. Any "browse baseline" was impossible, due to baseline cluttering.