# Identify the number of Binary files on each releases in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

we are using CC UCM Environment. I want to identify the number of binaries on each load/Release and making sure that we are packaging correctly the load.

Comment: Your questions is not clear... Add more details. What are the "binaries"? How are they related to CC?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice, when dealing with several source components which produce each their own binary, is to use **[composite baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613911/what-is-composite-baseline-in-ucm-and-when-it-will-be-used/9613986#9613986)**.
And you can have composite of composites.

[image: composite]

Each composite baseline records the baselines made on the direct dependent components, which allows you to:

- remember the association of baselines for a given release
- list each dependency, i.e. identifying the number of components involved.

Note though that this is for *source* components (you should not store binaries in a *source* control system like ClearCase)