# Jenkins Composite baseline with ClearCase

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I'm using the jenkins "ClearCase UCM Make baseline composite" plugin
and it seems that it checks a dynamic view on different machine (not the relevant one, on the build machine) - Does someone know why? Where does jenkins take this values from?

Another Q : The regular "ClearCase UCM baseline" plugin won't create a composite baseline.. But I read it should be able to do that, can I specify the root component through this plugin somehow?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The [JENKINS/ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) (whose [sources are available on GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-ucm-plugin)) is only working with [snapshot, not dynamic, views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309):

> The plugin will automatically create a snapshot view in a folder named 'view' in the root of the job's workspace.
>   Snapshot views can - as opposed to dynamic views - be located anywhere, which we exploit to place it inside the job's workspace.
>   Dynamic Views can only reside on the location where your mvfs is located and that is not inside the workspace.

A **[composite baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613986/6309)** is automatically created if the stream has a composite component, and composite dependencies have been defined (using that component as the root one) on said stream.
Setting a baseline on that stream should trigger the creation of a composite baseline, without you having to specify the root composite component.

Comment: It's not working for me. I have root component with all dependencies defined in ClearCase. Should I define it in jenkins?

Another thing - I know it's working with snapshot and I want it to work with snapshot, but somehow it's trying to reach some dynamic view on another nachine (not something I've configured)

Comment: @Sigalit no. The dependencies are defined on the stream only ("Edit baseline dependencies"). If there is a baseline set on one of the sub-components (meaning at least one file has changed), there will be one set on the root component.

Comment: It doesn't work.. baselines are created separately on each component and no baseline on root component. When I am doing it with the cleartool command it is working very well

Comment: @Sigalit then you can add to your current Jenkins job as a post-build step a `cleartool mkbl` step, just to ensure that the root component does get a baseline (if any were created during the job)