# Is there a way to create baseline for various projects in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is there a way to create one baseline for variuos different projects in ClearCase?

I need "Baseline of Baselines"

** Projects includes different VOBs

Thanks

Comment: It seems I already mentioned that composite baseline in a previous question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22126380/6309

Answer (score 0):

A baseline of baseline is called **composite baseline**: see "[What is composite baseline in UCM and when it will be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613986/6309)".

It means you have an UCM project with:

- your different root-based components (each one representing a "project", they can be in different vobs, it doesn't matter)
- a rootless component which will aggregate the other components.

Each time you will put a baseline on a stream with all those components, it will put a baseline:

- one each root-based component which have changed (new versions)
- one on the rootless component, in order to record the new list of baselines from its dependent components

The first time, you need to right-click on the stream and select "Edit baseline dependencies" in order to drag and drop all rootbased components under the rootless component.
That will establish the hierarchy of dependencies which will in turn enable the creation of the "baseline of baselines" you are after.